# Where to store application data for webapp?

Tags: html, jsp, tomcat, web-applications

I have some data for a webapp that I would like to store on the server. What would be a good location to put those files?

1. I have a couple of static HTML pages that contain instance specific information. They need to survive a re-deploy of the webapp. They need to be editable by the server's administrator. They are included in other HTML pages using the `html` object tag.
2. I want to store preferences on the server, but cannot use a database. I am using JSP to write and read the preferences. There is no sensitive data in the preferences. Currently I am using the log directory. But obviously that is not a great choice.

I am using Tomcat. I thought of creating an appdata/myapp directory under the webapp directory. Is that good or bad?

Comment: Bad, because depending on how you deploy, it could be wiped out. Better to have a configuration directory string in JNDI or static or dynamic-based-on-something and have the app read info from that directory.

Comment: Also, a local file may not work in a cluster

Comment: If its not under WEB-INF it can be served to the user.

Comment: Clustering is not a current requirement. If it were, an option would be to use a cluster file system location.

Answer (score 0):

If the server's administrator can also deploy the app, I would add the data file itself into the source control for the app, and deploy it all together. This way you get revision control of the data, and you get the ability to revert to known good data if the server fails.

If the administrator can't deploy the app, but can only edit the file, then you need plans to back up that file in the case that the server or server filesystem dies.

A third solution would be a hybrid: put the app in one source code repository. Put the data in a second source code repository. The administrator can edit the data and deploy the data. The developer can edit the app source code, and deploy the source code. This way, both are revision controlled, but you've separated responsibility for who maintains what.

Comment: The admin can deploy the app, but he has no access to source. The app is essentially a tool that can be downloaded by different departments for their own use.